# What do you put on Nation when filing out a Legal Document online? I'm from Puerto Rico

Tags: legal-terms, puerto-rico

I'm filing out a legal document online. Puerto Rico is never included under "Nation" when ordering stuff online, and it is always under "State" to make the process easier. But for the first time in my experience online, not only is Puerto Rico under "State", it is also under "Nation" and "Country" in the online legal document so now I'm confused. So do I put PR is "State" but also "Nation" and "Country"?

Comment: What's the document?  Chances are it doesn't matter very much.  Whether you say "Puerto Rico, USA" or "Puerto Rico, Puerto Rico," it's still the same Puerto Rico.

Comment: It's a Copyright registration. I was informed about eveything except that part, and so I'm not sure what to put.

Comment: Registering copyright with the US Copyright Office or with some other country?  Who informed you about the other items?  Are they asking for an address or the jurisdiction of first publication or for the nationality of the author or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The right answer depends upon the reason it is being asked.

For copyright registration, the United States as country and Puerto Rico as state should be the correct answer. Puerto Rico doesn't have copyright laws of its own.

Presumably, the ambiguity results from the IT people who programmed the interface not understanding the legal status of Puerto Rico and putting it everywhere "just in case".